# Can't covisualise objects in same plot using plot3d()

Tags: r, plot, rgl, .obj

Normally, this is fairly straight forward to acheive, however it is not working for .obj files I have read into R. One plot simply overwrites the preceding plot. Here is the code:

```
#read .obj files into R
fillskel_dnp=read.neuron("C:\\Users\\usr\\Dropbox\\WRITE.NEURON\\FILL TRACE\\DNP.obj")
fillskel=read.neuron("C:\\Users\\usr\\Dropbox\\WRITE.NEURON\\FILL TRACE\\fillobjnew.obj")

#process .obj files
fillskel.hbum=xform_brain(fillskel, reference = 'JRCFIB2018F', sample=T1, via=JFRC2)
fillskel.hbum_dnp=xform_brain(fillskel_dnp, reference = 'JRCFIB2018F', sample=JRC2018U, via=JFRC2)

#plot
open3d()
plot3d(fillskel.hbum, type='wire', col='black', lwd=3)
plot3d(fillskel.hbum_dnp,type='wire', col='Red', lwd=3)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your code isn't something we can run, but I think the answer is simply to use `add = TRUE` in the second plot.

Comment: @user2554330  you are a hero, thank you. I tried to upvote your comment but I am not allowed to for some reason.

Comment: That's probably because you are still a new user.  Once you get some more points, more options will open to you.  I'll put it in as an answer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking `plot3d` clears the window (or moves to the next frame) before plotting.  If you don't want that to happen, use the `add = TRUE` argument, i.e. your last commands should be

```
#plot
open3d()
plot3d(fillskel.hbum, type='wire', col='black', lwd=3)
plot3d(fillskel.hbum_dnp,type='wire', col='Red', lwd=3, add = TRUE)
```